# How to Have 2 Code Coverages in Gitlab Repo Badges

Tags: unit-testing, gitlab, code-coverage, gitlab-ci-runner

My team has a gitlab repo. It has two parts: an NPM package under projects folder and an angular application under src folder. So there are 2 projects in the `angular.json` file.

We currently have unit tests with coverage setup in our gitlab pipes. The issue is, since we have 2 projects in this repo, we really need to show the coverage for each project.

I noticed in demo image of the gitlab badges documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/badges.html), they have a 'JS Coverage' badge. This seems to be a custom badge (I can't find a list of given badges, but I'm not finding anything for 'JS coverage', so I'm assuming it's custom).

So I think I can do something like that to create 2 custom badges that has the code coverage of each project (1 for 'Pkg Coverage' and 1 for 'App Coverage'). But (TBH) the documentation around creating custom badges isn't great. I need to know how to store this custom value to use in the badge, and how to update in the gitlab pipe.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? If I could just figure out how that example is using 'JS Coverage' (and how to update the value in the pipe), then I could figure out what I need to do for my 2 custom badges. Any tips?

Some details, right now we have a gitlab job like this (it runs unit tests and updates the coverage values. Since 'ng test' runs the tests of both projects 1 by 1, the code coverage of the 1st project is saved to the 'coverage' value):

```
unit-tests:
  stage: test
  rules:
    # Run unit tests, including when merge requests are merged to default branch (so coverage % is updated)
    - when: on_success
  image: trion/ng-cli-karma:$ANGULAR_VERSION
  before_script:
    - *angular-env-setup-script
  coverage: '/Statements \W+: (\d+\.\d+)%.*/'
  script:
    - npm run build:ds-prod
    - npm install dist/ds
    - ng test --code-coverage --progress false --watch false
  artifacts:
    expose_as: "Coverage Report"
    paths:
      - coverage/
  tags:
    - kubernetes-runner
```

Comment: Are you using a self managed or gitlab.com instance?

Comment: Might be worth having a look at https://shields.io/category/coverage

Comment: you can also make your own badge if you dont have a public project like https://img.shields.io/badge/Foo%20Coverage-89.43%25-yellowgreen

Comment: I believe we are using a self managed gitlab.com instance. The domain is {my-company-name}.gitlab.com, so seems like an instance to me. i'll check those suggestions out TY